# How dynamically change API endpoint on Angularjs services based on the domain or host application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have MVC web application that use Angularjs and a Web API, both application are published in different domains. Everytime thet I commit code changes TFS publish both the MVC app and the Web API and using web.config transformation it change the web config connection and app keys to point to developer, production or testing.

Now that I am using angular I have a service that point to the API endpoint to do something for instance the login.

...

```
function loginService($http, $q) {

        var baseUri = "http://localhost/"

        var service = {
            login: login,
           ...
        };

        return service;


        function login(user, password) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({ method: 'POST', url: baseUri + '/api/tokens',
...
```

As you can see the baseUri is set to localhost but I would like it have for the production environment something like  `var baseUri = "http://production/"` and for testing `baseUri = "http://testing/"`. SO the baseUri changes depend of what is being publish by TFS.

Remember the the domain where the MVC application is hosted is different of the WebAPI so I cannot check the domain of the angular scope and build the base URI.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do a switch on the domain of the MVC app and based on whichever it is build the URI for the API?

So something like:

```
switch (MVCdomain) {
    case "http://production/": baseUri = "http://APIproduction/"; break;
    case "http://testing/": baseUri = "http://APItesting/"; break;
}
```

Could probably encapsulate that in its own endpointService that you can inject into your loginService or any other service that needs it, something like this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app').factory('endpointService', function ($location) {
        return {
            getAPIEndpoint: function () {
                var endpoint = '';
                switch ($location.host()) {
                    // test if MVC app is in prod/test/local and determine what API endpoint should be called
                    case 'ProdDomainP.com': endpoint = 'ProdDomainAPIP.com'; break;
                    case 'TestDomainP.com': endpoint = 'TestDomainAPIP.com'; break;
                }
                return endpoint;
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

This would be a service you inject into other services to determine what API endpoint you call, like so:

```
function loginService($http, $q, endpointService) {

    var baseUri = endpointService.getAPIEndoint();

    var service = {
        login: login,
       ...
    };

    return service;


    function login(user, password) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ method: 'POST', url: baseUri + '/api/tokens',
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This could be a possible solution but what I am trying to dont have a API call to get URIs. Maybe is not possible and I will need to do that but what I will like is to have that injected on the publication process or something similar

Comment: I'm confused, this isn't using an API call to determine the URIs. Let me know if I understand correctly. Your MVC application is put on one domain and your Web API is on a separate one. With angularjs code in your MVC application you are making calls to the Web API, and based on where the MVC application is (production, testing, local) you want to call the appropriate API endpoint (production testing, local)?

Comment: Yes Ben Black you are right both the MVC app and the Web API has different environments(domians) based on the release(Production ,test, etc). For instance the MVC app on production will be hosted on domianP.com and its API will be on domianApiP.com. This MVC will call endpoints on domianApiP.com. ALl these different publication happens automatically. Basally when TFS publish the MVC app the ng js code should have them on Production basicURI =domianApiP.com.

Comment: I could do and AJAX call to my MVC application and get the domain but I am trying to avoid an extra call.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to do that. However you should be able, in angular using the `$location` service, to tell what environment (production, test, local) your MVC app is in and then construct the API endpoint URI, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do this as well. So I don't have to hard code api endpoints in my angular app, before I bootstrap angular, I make a service call in JavaScript to get endpoints. On the server side (web api) the controller reads from the web.config to get the end points that the angular app will use and returns them as JSON. Then , still before I bootstrap angular and after the endpoints are returned to JavaScript (via a native js promise or angular promise) , I set a global object var that holds all end points. In angular there is an endpoint service that exposes this global end points object. Finally when that endpoint object is set, I bootstrap angular app. This ensures the endpoints are set before angular runs and tries tobuse the endpoints.

It sucks there needs to be this global endpoint object that exists outside of angular but it's the only way I can think of allows usage of web.config for transforms and not have to hardcode URL endpoint in js

Comment: Well, it _tries_ (in a long-winded way) and seems to describe something similar to the accepted answer.